# How do I generate a list of commands to evaluate a mathematical expression on a stack machine using parse trees and a tokenizer?

Tags: java, token, lexer, stringtokenizer, parse-tree

So I am trying to create a **CalcParser** class that, when given a mathematical expression, generates a string containing commands to evaluate the expression on a stack machine. For example, 1+2*3 should output:

push 1.0
push 2.0
push 3.0
multiply
add

Also, parentheses must be observed. So (1+2)*3 should output:

push 1.0
push 2.0
add
push 3.0
multiply

I am working with a pre-existing **CalcLexer** class that holds the string being parsed and converts it into a series of tokens using `java.util.StringTokenizer`. The only piece of information necessary from this class is the operators **\t\n\r+-*/()** and **whitespace** are also considered individual tokens.

Here is my question. If I were using parse trees to generate the output code, how would I take into account the parentheses since an expression inside parentheses will always be done first? Here is what I have so far for the `parseRootexp()` method, and I have a feeling I'm a bit off:

```
private double value;
private CalcLexer lexer = new CalcLexer();
private void parseRootexp(){
    if (lexer.nextToken() == '('){
        match('(');
        do{
            lexer.nextToken();
            if (lexer.nextToken() == CalcLexer.NUMBER_TOKEN){
                value = lexer.getNum();
                System.out.println("push " + value + "\n");
            }   
        } while (lexer.nextToken() != ')');
    }
}
```

The `match(int token)` method is used simply to match the current token with an allowable terminal symbol. If not, an error is returned. I know this is far from what I want ideally, but what I need is something to push me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your title is essentially meaningless. The string will contain the expression, and you need to write *code* to evaluate it.

Comment: What would you recommend as a title so that I properly state what it is I need? I am new here.

Comment: 'Generate a list of commands ' is no better. You have to *write* the *code.* Stop beating about the bush.